# OnPropertyValidating method for CustomModelBinder never gets called

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi I am new to asp net mvc programming and I am wondering why the OnPropertyValidating method for my CustomModelBinder class is not being called.

Here is my declaration for the CUstomModelBinder.

```
public class TestModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    protected override bool OnPropertyValidating(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, object value)
    {
        if (value is string && (controllerContext.HttpContext.Request.ContentType.StartsWith("application/json", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))
        {
            if (controllerContext.Controller.ValidateRequest && bindingContext.PropertyMetadata[propertyDescriptor.Name].RequestValidationEnabled)
            {
                int index;
                if (IsDangerousString(value.ToString(), out index))
                {
                    throw new HttpRequestValidationException("Dangerous Input Detected");
                }
            }               
        }
        return base.OnPropertyValidating(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, value);
    }
```

}

and here is what I added to the Global.asax

```
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TestModelBinder), new TestModelBinder());
    ModelBinders.Binders.DefaultBinder = new TestModelBinder();
```

now I am assuming that this OnPropertyValidating method will get called everytime I call a controller action something like :

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult TestMethod(int param1, string param2, string param3)
{
    ...
}
```

but the OnPropertyValidating method on my customModelBinder never gets called.

Can anyone help me to understand why? Is there any good tutorial sites for this?

Thank in advance!

Comment: Have you tried setting the DefaultBinder to an instance which is actually in the Binders collection? Just a wild guess...

Comment: Can you explain what that means? I am new to asp net programming. Can you point me to a good tutorial about this?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(TestModelBinder), new TestModelBinder());
```

Do this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(<your model>), new TestModelBinder());
```